# Pass entire Array in php in another array

Tags: php, arrays, payment-gateway

I have array with products its name is $item

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Quantity] => 2
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Barbula klandoa  - Caryopteris clandonensis  
                    [UnitPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [Gross] => 1480
                            [Net] => 0
                            [Tax] => 0
                            [TaxRate] => 0
                            [CurrencyCode] => PLN
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Quantity] => 1
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Aronia czarnoowocowa Nero - Aronia melanocarpa Nero
                    [UnitPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [Gross] => 1200
                            [Net] => 0
                            [Tax] => 0
                            [TaxRate] => 0
                            [CurrencyCode] => PLN
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Quantity] => 1
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Ambrowiec Amerykański P9 - Liquidambar styraciflua
                    [UnitPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [Gross] => 1300
                            [Net] => 0
                            [Tax] => 0
                            [TaxRate] => 0
                            [CurrencyCode] => PLN
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

no i have to passed it to this:

```
    $shoppingCart = array(
    'GrandTotal' => ($suma_z_produktow*10),
    'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN',
    'ShoppingCartItems' => array (

                array ('ShoppingCartItem' => $item)

    )
);
```

Result is that only last entry from this array is passed to this new array.
I can nodifi it and pass it like that:

```
$shoppingCart = array(
    'GrandTotal' => ($suma_z_produktow*10),
    'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN',
    'ShoppingCartItems' => array (

                array ('ShoppingCartItem' => $item[0)
    array ('ShoppingCartItem' => $item[1)

    )
);
```

that method works, but I dont know how many product will customer order. Is there any method to pass all items in 1 row?

Its for Payu Payment method integration.
Thx

Comment: have you tried implode()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$shoppingCart = array(
    'GrandTotal' => ($suma_z_produktow*10),
    'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN',
    'ShoppingCartItems' => array (),
);

foreach($item as $cartItem){
    $shoppingCart['ShoppingCartItems'][] = array('ShoppingCartItem'=>$cartItem);
}

print_r($shoppingCart);
```

This will build up the `shoppingCartItems` for as many items as you have.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to tweak your code to get it to do what you want. Here is what I would recommend:

```
$shoppingCart = array(
    'GrandTotal' => ($suma_z_produktow*10),
    'CurrencyCode' => 'PLN',
    'ShoppingCartItems' => array (),
);

foreach($item as $product) {
    $shoppingCart['ShoppingCartItems'][] = array('ShoppingCartItem' => $product);
}
```